# How can I catch requests in mozswing?

Tags: java, mozilla, xpcom, xulrunner

I would like to catch requests made by mozswing when a the user click on a link, or submit a form so that the socket connection is never made and I can answer the request "myself".

Comment: hello, have you found a solution? i need it too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to do. I hope this helps somebody.

EDIT: Best way to listen for links:

```
final ContentAdapter ca = moz.getChromeAdapter().getContentAdapter();

nsIURIContentListener mycl = new nsIURIContentListener() {
    public boolean onStartURIOpen(nsIURI aURI) {
        System.out.println(aURI.getHost() + aURI.getPath());
        return true;
    }
    public boolean doContent(String aContentType, boolean aIsContentPreferred, nsIRequest aRequest, nsIStreamListener[] aContentHandler) { 
        System.out.println("1");
        return ca.doContent(aContentType, aIsContentPreferred, aRequest, aContentHandler); 
    }
    public boolean isPreferred(String aContentType, String[] aDesiredContentType) { 
        System.out.println("2");
        return ca.isPreferred(aContentType, aDesiredContentType); 
    }
    public boolean canHandleContent(String aContentType, boolean aIsContentPreferred, String[] aDesiredContentType) { 
        System.out.println("3");
        return ca.canHandleContent(aContentType, aIsContentPreferred, aDesiredContentType); 
    }
    public nsISupports getLoadCookie() { 
        System.out.println("4");
        return ca.getLoadCookie(); 
    }
    public void setLoadCookie(nsISupports aLoadCookie) { 
        System.out.println("5");
        ca.setLoadCookie(aLoadCookie); 
    }
    public nsIURIContentListener getParentContentListener() { 
        System.out.println("6");
        return ca.getParentContentListener(); 
    }
    public void setParentContentListener(nsIURIContentListener aParentContentListener) { 
        System.out.println("7");
        ca.setParentContentListener(aParentContentListener); 
    }
    public nsISupports queryInterface(String uuid) { 
        System.out.println("8");
        return ca.queryInterface(uuid); 
    }
 };

 moz.getChromeAdapter().getWebBrowser().setParentURIContentListener(mycl);
```

Comment: That's not quite what I was looking for. I wanted to catch request made by the browser so that they never hit the socket and instead directly process the request and answer to it. I'm not sure it's feasible anyway. The idea behind this is being able to deploy a web based application through webstart without having to ask for special permissions to the user.